# Importance of the average mark

Tags: interviewing, job-search, job-offer, applications, germany

As suggested in [this comment](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/37950/importance-of-the-average-mark?noredirect=1#comment83912_37950) on [academia.stackexchange.com](https://academia.stackexchange.com/), I'm moving my question here:

I'm doing my master's degree in computer science in a university in Germany. Unfortunately, I'm not one of the best students; my average mark will be around 2.8 (on a scale of 1 to 5, where 1 is the best mark).

How important is the average mark when applying for a job?

I know, there are other important factors, such as work experience, etc.
But I'm afraid that if another applicant has an average mark of, say, 1.8, they will just ignore my application.

Comment: Is your question is specific to Germany and employers located within Germany?

Comment: Depends a lot on the company. But assuming you're applying to a programming job, you should be able to find companies that mainly care about your skill and less about your academic achievements.

Comment: Would you switch careers or are there any options to improve your grades? If you apply and get turned-down for your marks, you'll have your answer. Otherwise, it really depends on the company even though there may be some consensus on where to cut-off candidates based on marks in you part of the  world.

Comment: Saying the scale is 1-5 is a bit misleading, since passing grades are between 1.0 and 4.0, and 5 is just used to mark a failed course which has to be repeated and never enter into the calculation of the average grade. [I'm not 100% sure if it's like that everywhere in Germany, but with was like that for me]

Comment: This is a duplicated post of the linked question (which has been migrated here from Academia with an answeR).